# Tree Structure in python using CSV data

Tags: python, tree, visualization, data-science

I have a csv file having data as id,name and parentid and i want to draw a tree using that data file.Please help

I did this codebut pandas is not working

```
from ete3 import Tree
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
f=open("UdemyT21.csv","r")
csvreader=csv.reader(f)
next(f)
test=list(csvreader)
header=['ID','Name','ParentId']

mydict = {rows[0]:rows[2] for rows in test}
for key in mydict.items():
  for value in mydict.items():
    if value==None:
        t=Tree(key)
        t.show()        
    else:
        t=Tree("(value,key);")
        t.show()
```

Comment: Did you make any code so far?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ete3 library `pip install ete3 PyQt5`. The tutorial to export the tree to png can be found [here](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html?highlight=png).

An example of this, assuming you have the csv loaded as an array [parent, id] (assuming id is the name):

```
from ete3 import Tree, TreeStyle, TextFace, add_face_to_node
from collections import defaultdict

def build_tree(nodes):
    root = None
    for i in nodes:
        if i[0] == -1:
            root = i
    if not root:
        raise ValueError('no root!')
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for i in nodes:
        if i[0] != -1:
            data[i[1]] = []
            data[i[0]].append(i[1])
    return data, root[1]

def dict_tree_to_str(tree, root):
    if not tree[root]:
        return f'{root}'
    subtrees = [dict_tree_to_str(tree, st) for st in tree[root]]
    return f'({",".join(subtrees)}){root}'

tree_csv = [[-1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [5, 7]]
tree_dict, root = build_tree(tree_csv)
t = Tree(dict_tree_to_str(tree_dict, root)+';',  format=1)

ts = TreeStyle()
ts.show_leaf_name = False
def my_layout(node): # https://github.com/etetoolkit/ete/issues/219
    F = TextFace(node.name, tight_text=True)
    add_face_to_node(F, node, column=0, position="branch-right")
ts.layout_fn = my_layout

t.render("mytree.png", w=183, units="mm", tree_style=ts)
```